# Want to import bits (a couple of rows) of an .txt to excel

Tags: vba, excel, import

Hey so i found a specific query to import a file into excel from a specific row and delete the following datga each time you open it again. but is it also pssible to stop adding rows at a specific line? and is it possible to leave some rows out if there for example is a specific word in that line?

```html
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\sample.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but not with a Querytable. 
Try this code:

```
Private Sub Open_Click()
Dim fn As Variant, myLine As Long, txt As String, x As Variant, ouput As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer: j = 1
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Modify Sheet Name

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
       "Open File")
If fn = False Then Exit Sub
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
x = Split(txt, vbNewLine)

For i = 0 To UBound(x)
    If x(i) <> "SomeCriteria" Then 'Check for some criteria
        sht.Cells(j, 1).Value = x(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

So what it does basically, it opens a user selected txt file and stores it in the variable `txt`. Do seperate the rows you can use the `split`-function. Now each line is stored in an array `x`. You could go trough the array/each line and take out the ones you want. To check if a specific word is in a line, use the `InStr`-function.

Comment: Tank you for your answer, can you tell me where i insert the textfile , where do i need to change the code and input the thread of my text file?

Comment: Just run the code, it will open a file dialog and you can select a .txt file.

Comment: Okay, yes it opened the dialog but after that it showed the result in a msg box, but did not import it in an sheet, do i need to change something?

Comment: This is meant to be an example, not a solution for your exact problem. The lines are stored in the array `x`, use it to give out the line you want into the sheet.

Comment: could you explain how to use array x to determine a specific line?

Comment: What helps is to go trough your code with `F8` line by line, you can hover over the variables to see the values. I edited my code to give out the lines in a sheet. In the `For` loop i go trough the array aka lines with the index `i`. If you are not familar with array and how they are build up, you should go look them up.